# Why GraphQL-Ruby does not understand dynamically generated schema definitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

In Rails app, I have the following part of the schema defined:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Types
  module KVInfo
    def self.kv_value_scalar(typename, raw_type: String, typeid:)
      clazz = Class.new(BaseObject) do
        graphql_name "KVEntry#{typename}Value"

        field :value, raw_type, null: false
      end

      clazz.define_singleton_method(:typeid) { typeid }
      clazz.define_singleton_method(:typename) { typename }

      clazz
    end

    # typeids taken from enum in (.../kv_info.ts)
    KVScalars = [
      kv_value_scalar('String', typeid: 0),
      kv_value_scalar('Markdown', typeid: 1),
      kv_value_scalar(
        'Date',
        raw_type: GraphQL::Types::ISO8601DateTime,
        typeid: 2
      ),
      kv_value_scalar('Country', typeid: 3),
      kv_value_scalar('Address', typeid: 5)
    ].freeze

    KVScalars.each { |t| KVInfo.const_set(t.graphql_name, t) }

    class KVScalarValue < BaseUnion
      possible_types(*KVScalars)

      def self.resolve_type(obj, _ctx)
        KVScalars.select { |t| t.typeid == obj['type'] }.first
      end
    end

    def self.kv_value_array(subtype)
      clazz = Class.new(BaseObject) do
        graphql_name "KVEntryArray#{subtype.typename}"

        field :value, [subtype], null: false
      end

      clazz.define_singleton_method(:sub_typeid) { subtype.typeid }

      clazz
    end

    KVArrays = KVScalars.map { |s| kv_value_array(s) }

    KVArrays.each { |t| KVInfo.const_set(t.graphql_name, t) }

    class KVArrayValue < BaseUnion
      possible_types(*KVArrays)

      def self.resolve_type(obj, _ctx)
        KVArrays.select { |t| t.sub_typeid == obj['subtype'] }
      end
    end

    class KVValue < BaseUnion
      # PP HERE
      possible_types(KVArrayValue, KVScalarValue)

      def self.resolve_type(obj, _ctx)
        obj['type'] == 4 ? # typeid for array
          KVArrayValue :
          KVScalarValue
      end
    end

    class KVEntry < BaseObject
      field :name, String, null: false
      field :value, KVValue, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

While running a Rake task that dumps the whole schema to a file to be consumed by frontend, I see the type denoted by `KVEntry` class having only the `name` field.
If I put all possible types in the `KVValue` class like such:

```rb
pp(*KVScalars, *KVArrays)
possible_types(*KVScalars, *KVArrays)
```

it works and generates types correctly.
But note the `pp` line above - it does not work without this line (???).
Also, if I keep it as is (with nested unions), it does not work regardless of number and positions of `pp` clauses. When going through with the debugger, all classes are loaded correctly, including generated ones, but the schema still lacks required types.

So the question is *what the bisq...* why the types are not processed and how can `pp` affect this process in any sense?

P.S. The data format is fixed by frontend and no way subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the nested unions. GraphQL does not support these. And on the part of plain union not working - I still have no idea of reasons for such behavior, but it fixed itself after N-th restart.